# Get PropertyInfo of a parameter passed as lambda expression | Compact Framework, C#

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, compact-framework

Say I have following Asset class:

```
class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to write a method `GetPropertyInfo(a=>a.Name);` and this method gives me the PropertyInfo of Asset.Name. I should be able to call this method like:

**EDIT Example Method Call**

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = GetPropertyInfo(a=>a.Name);
```

I have a `List<PropertyInfo>` so I want to match a given lambda expression with those in my list.

```
if(Possible on Compact Framework 3.5 && using C#)
    How?
else
    Please Notify
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done under .NETCF 3.5.

```
private List<Asset> m_list;

private Asset[] GetPropertyInfo(string name) {
  var items = m_list.Where(a => a.Name == name);
  if (items != null) {
    return items.ToArray();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

You will, however, need to initialize the `m_list` and fill it with your data first.

**UPDATE:**

So, your list is of type `PropertyInfo` and you want a call to get the type that matches a particular `Asset` object.

If that is correct, you could simply edit the code above to be as follows:

```
private List<PropertyInfo> m_list;

private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Asset a) {
  return m_list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == a.Name);
}
```

I am not sure how you are getting the `List<PropertyInfo>`, though. I was able to pull a single `PropertyInfo` object using the code below:

```
private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo() {
  var t = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.MemberInfo");
  return t.GetProperty("Name");
}
```

There was nothing useful in this item.

Comment: You got me wrong. I want PropertyInfo object belonging to asset.Name property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx

Comment: Edit your original post to show exactly what you are pulling and how you do it with conventional code. Perhaps then I'll understand enough to help you. The Executing Assembly has a lot of properties and methods.

Comment: I added how I want to call my method. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you need done. I updated my code, but I don't think you will be pulling much information using Reflection from mobile devices.